# Determine total current in a darlington transistor

Tags: current, bjt, darlington

I'm trying to figure out what will be the total current consumption of a TIP120.

[image]

Looking at the internal schematic I see that the second BJT's base is following the emitter of the first one so it will consume current proportional to the base current of the first one but I'm having a hard time determining the exact values. The ones given in the datasheet are for the entire pair, right? How can I determine what current will be consumed by the base-emmiter paths with a 500mA load on the collector of the pair?

Additionally what is the role of the voltage divider? If current follows the path of least resistance then this must mean there will not be any current going through the resistors? (which is certainly not the case)

Comment: The statement of current following the path of least resistance, it isn't technically true, otherwise parallel circuits just wouldn't work! Are you wanting to solve for each individual transistor in the Darlington pair? Or are you just interested in the part as a whole? You are correct that the datasheet values are for the pair, as the TIP120 has a Darlington pair built inside. The transistors inside should be well matched, so you can solve the circuit as if it is a single transistor with a B, C and E. Unfortunately, the datasheet doesn't give an exact beta value

Comment: @MCG basically I'm curious to find out how much on top of my load's 500mA will be drawn, because the second transistor of the pair gets its base current from the same current source as my load.

Comment: In that case, yes, you should be able to solve that as if you were using a single transistor. As Bimpelrekkie mentions in his answer, the current gain for each part can vary, as you can see in the datasheet, only a minimum value is provided.

Comment: *I'm curious to find out how much on top of my load's 500mA will be drawn* If we assume \$h_{FE}\$ = 1000 that then means \$I_B\$ = 0.5 mA. I would add some margin so I would make \$I_B\$ = 1 mA to switch a 500 mA load. Your question "how much does it add" is basically irrelevant as I doubt that your 500 mA load is **exactly** 500 mA, I mean 1 mA is only 0.2% of 500 mA. Is your 500 mA accurate to within 0.2 % ? Often 1% accuracy is already quite accurate, then the 1 mA base current falls within the 500 mA load current's error margin.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I'm taking 500mA theoretically, if we have to consider a realistic scenario then I have a LED bulb that's rated at 12v 6w which solves to 500mA but when measured it actually draws 650mA. If I have to feed 1mA into the base of the pair then I still can't understand how to determine how much current will be drawn for the second transistor's base.

Comment: *I still can't understand how to determine how much current will be drawn for the second transistor's base.* 1) for that we would need to know the \$h_{FE}\$ of the second transistor, we don't know this value, we only know the product of the \$h_{FE}\$ of both transistors (in a darlington the \$h_{FE}\$s are multiplied. 2) that current is **irrelevant**, why? Ask yourself how this current (base current of 2nd transistor) flows, what provides it. Does it flow into the Darlington's base or the collector?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie the entire thing started because I wanted to compare which was more efficient an IRLZ44N MOSFET or TIP120. I calculated for the MOSFET that by applying 3.3v at the gate I will have Rdson of around 0.05 ohm, which will lead to a power loss of 0.05 * 0.65 * 0.65 = 20mW. Being a 12V circuit this gives 0.02/12 = 0.001A lost to heat. However if I want to switch more than one bulb the loss increases exponentially, so I want to calculate the same for the darlington pair and determine what will be the loss if I switch all of my 6 bulbs with 1 transistor.

Comment: You do the calculation and without doing that I can already tell you that a MOSFET will be more efficient (less power lost when switched on) as: 1) the gate needs no current other than to switch on/off 2) the voltage drop Vds will be **much** smaller as a MOSFET acts as a low value resistor (Rds,on) while an NPN needs some saturation voltage and a Darlington is even worse as an extra Vbe is needed.

Comment: Use a TIP120 if you MUST but a MOSFET solution will be superior in most cases.

Comment: The base current for the output transistor comes from the load, but it requires a diode drop to get that current so a Darlington will always drop more than a diode drop, which translates into a lot of power dissipation if the current is high. A proper logic-level MOSFET will be more efficient usually. The IRLZ44 is not guaranteed Rds(on) with Vgs < 4.0V so you should pick a more appropriate part for comparison rather than rolling the dice with your 3.3V nominal drive, or boost the drive voltage to 5V or 10V so you can  use a wider range of MOSFETs (even sub-1m\$\Omega\$ parts).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany the easiest way I could think of in order to boost my 3.3V is to step down my battery's 12V to 5V and feed that into the collector of a BJT (BD179 for example, I have a bunch laying around) and use my micro controller's 3.3V signal on its base. Then connect the emitter to the gate of the IRLZ44N and I'll essentially be creating the scheme of the darlington pair except the secondary will be a MOSFET. That doesn't seem right, what would be a proper way to step up those micro controller 3.3V signals if I have tens of them?

Comment: If it's a relatively benign 500mA maximum load (no short circuit tolerance or other such requirement) I would just use an SOT-23 N-channel MOSFET like the AO3400A with 100K gate pull-down. It's less than 48m\$\Omega\$ with >2.5V drive so at 0.5A it will dissipate less than 12mW, just about nothing. Just make sure that the brown-out condition is locked out (eg. enable BOR on your MCU and put the aforementioned pull-downs in place).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany well actually the IRLZ44N has a Vgs of 2V max so it will definitely work fine on 3.3V. I guess your point was that I can't be certain of the resistance at that voltage but I'm guessing it will be somewhere around 0.05 (hence the calculations I mentioned). It's still pretty close to the resistance of the AO3400A? I apologize if I appear to be ignorant, I don't really understand what your concern is.

Comment: @php_nub_qq If you're switching no more than 250uA it's fine with 2V, yes. Between 2V and 4V nothing is guaranteed. Worse at temperature extremes of course. That's what "roll the dice" means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with the information that is given for the current gain \$h_{FE}\$, you should be able to extract a "ballpark figure" [from the datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/TIP120.pdf):

[image]

Note how that information is quite "basic", all that the manufacturer guarantees is that \$h_{FE}\$ will be larger than 1000.

So you will **not** be able to find an **exact** value because \$h_{FE}\$ will never have an exact value, unless you take a transistor and measure it, then you have **that** transistor's \$h_{FE}\$ at the conditions at which you measured it. The next transistor in the box might have a **completey different** \$h_{FE}\$!

So stop trying to find an **exact** value for beta. What engineers do is that they design the **circuit** around this transistor such that it will work reliably for \$h_{FE}\$ = 1000 and higher values. (And most engineers would also add some margin to that so would design for \$h_{FE}\$ > 500 just to be sure).

The resistors don't really work as a a voltage divider as there are also the base-emitters in parallel with these resistors. The resistors are there to make sure the transistors switch off when no input current (at the base) is applied. Since the TIP120 is designed for switching applications, this makes sense. Without these resistors it would take longer to discharge the base of the "big" transistor when we want to switch it off.